# Chrome sync pass phrase forgets itself on copy

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using [Google chrome portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable). Whenever I move chrome from the server to my local computer (it runs better this way) it forgets the pass phrase. Why?

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: From [the page you linked to](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable): "We've added password portability as an advanced option, though, which you can enable by reading the help.html file." Have you read the file?

Comment: @Ramhound I want to fix the problem that I can't transfer my passphrase.

Comment: @ForeverWintr I have not read it, but when I just looked at it I couldn't find out how to do so.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - Have you read the  help.html file which explains how to do what you want in detail.

Comment: @Ramhound I read it but I couldn't find the part that tells me how to do it, just the part that tells me I can do it.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - I took a look and I was able to find it.

Comment: @Ramhound I still don't see it. What's a couple words from it so I can just use F3? I, for whatever reason, can't find the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Chrome encrypts these passwords using your Windows logon password.

This is also the reason why you would lose all your Chrome passwords if you forgot your Windows password.